# Does Python set update() replace existing items?

Tags: python-3.x, set

If I use `my_set.update(my_list)` where some elements of `my_list` are `==` existing elements in `my_set`, does it replace the existing items or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It doesn't:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyType:
    hashed: int      # This will contribute to hash equality
    not_hashed: str  # This won't contribute to hash equality

    # Override hashing/equality
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return hash(self) == hash(other)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.hashed, ))

x = { MyType(hashed=1, not_hashed="original") }  # Add an item to a set
x.update([MyType(1, "new")])  # .update() with a different item with the same hash
print(x)

# { MyType(hashed=1, not_hashed='original') }  # The original item is in the set
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not replace existing elements, as can be seen from the following example:

```
>>> s = {1}
>>> s.add(1.0)
>>> s
{1}
```

The same behavior holds for dictionary *keys*:

```
>>> d = {1: 'foo'}
>>> d.update({1.0: 'bar'})
>>> d
{1: 'bar'}
```